# uri and android attributes not being allowed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to enter code here been trying to get more search activity into my action bar but I keep on getting this error code that my Uri is not registered and I cant use some of the android attributes except for name its frustrating. Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kwame.myactionbardemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >'
```

Comment: @jaYjaY whats the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have entered this into to wrong section. Add this to the androidmanifest.xml file.